# places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchText

Tags: c#, vb.net, httpclient

Good evening everyone, I ask you for help as I am not a wizard, but I need to implement this Google API Place (new) in VB.NET. I've been fighting for days.
I received this message after a long wait: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: 'An activity has been cancelled.'
below is my code:

```
Dim Client = New HttpClient()
Dim request = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,     "https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchText")
request.Headers.Add("X-Goog-Api-Key", My.Settings.APIKey_Google)
request.Headers.Add("X-Goog-FieldMask",   "places.displayName,places.formattedAddress,places.businessStatus,places.location,places.types,place   s.rating,places.userRatingCount")
Dim content = New StringContent("{" & vbCrLf & """textQuery"": ""B&B in San Marzano sul Sarno SA, Campania""" & vbCrLf & "}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
request.Content = content
Dim response = Await client.SendAsync(request)
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
Console.WriteLine(Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())`
```

In reality, if I try the call with Postman everything goes smoothly and I receive a correct answer. the code that produces Postman in C# is the following (and produces the same error):

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,  "https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchText");
request.Headers.Add("X-Goog-Api-Key", My.Settings.APIKey_Google);
request.Headers.Add("X-Goog-FieldMask", "places.displayName,places.formattedAddress,places.businessStatus,places.location,places.types,place s.rating,places.userRatingCount");
var content = new StringContent("{\r\n\"textQuery\": \"B&B in San Marzano sul Sarno SA,  Campania\"\r\n}", null, "application/json");
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

I also tried calling like this (I get the error: Remote Server Error: (400) Invalid request.) Actually, in this case I wasn't able to add the query to the body of the request.

```
Dim apiKey As String = My.Settings.APIKey_Google
Dim request As WebRequest =  WebRequest.Create("https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchText")
request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentType = "application/json"
request.Headers.Add("X-Goog-Api-Key", apiKey)
request.Headers.Add("X-Goog-FieldMask", "places.displayName")
request.Headers.Add("textQuery", "Parrucchieri in San Marzano sul Sarno SA, Campania")
request.ContentLength = 0
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

    Try

        Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            Using reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                Dim pippo = reader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim pippo1 = "Errore: " & ex.Message

    End Try
```

In the Google spec guide I read: "Pass all parameters in the JSON request body or in headers as part of the POST request. For example:"

`curl -X POST -d '{ "textQuery" : "Spicy Vegetarian Food in Sydney, Australia" }' \ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-Goog-Api-Key: API_KEY' \ -H 'X-Goog-FieldMask: places.displayName,places.formattedAddress,places.priceLevel' \ 'https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchText'`